# Can I dynamically show and hide an HTML element

Tags: angular6

In `HTML`, I can show or hide an eleement by adding a property `display:none` or 'display:block`. Can I do this dynamically from my`Angular` component.

I have a `textarea` in my html which i want to show when a button is clicked. However, I can't see any property in `HTMLTextAreaElement` to do this

```
let ref = this.titleTextArea.nativeElement as HTMLTextAreaElement;
```

how can I make `ref` show or hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **click** event to do this or you can use **element.style.display** property to show or hide HTMLElement

```
let textArea =(document.getElementById('textarea2') as HTMLTextAreaElement)
textArea.style.display ='block'
```

[click here to see example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-show-hide-textarea?file=src/app/app.component.ts)